# Do-While Qualifiers and Totalling in Java

Tags: java

I am trying my hand a few basic do-while codes, and am running into a couple of problems.

I want the code to ask the user to input 1 of 3 options (choosing which group they would like to add a number to, or to exit and total), give an error if they input an irrelevant option, and then total all ints at the end for each group.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String answer = "default";
    int grp1 = 0;
    int grp2 = 0;
    int input1 = 0;
    int input2 = 0;

    do{
        System.out.println("Make a selection:\n");
        System.out.println("A: Enter a number for Group 1.");
        System.out.println("B: Enter a number for Group 2.");
        System.out.println("X: Exit and total the numbers for each group.\n");
        System.out.println("Select your option: ");
        answer = keyboard.next();

        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("A")){
            System.out.println("Enter int: ");
            input1 = keyboard.nextInt();        // add an int to grp1
        }
        else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("B")){
            System.out.println("Enter int: ");
            input2 = keyboard.nextInt();        // add an int to grp2
        }
        else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("X")){ 
        }                                       // exit and total
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid option - Try again.");
        }                                       // Invalid input - restart

    }

    while (answer.equals("A") || answer.equals("B"));

    grp1 += input1;
    grp2 += input2;

    keyboard.close();

    System.out.println("Group 1's total is: + grp1);
    System.out.println("Group 2's total is: + grp2);        
}
```

I need the to add a qualifier for if the user does not input a valid option, I tried using *else*:

```
else {
System.out.println("Invalid option - Try again.") 
}
```

but this just skips to printing the totals, and does not ask the user for another input. How would I best achieve this?

Also,

```
grp1 += input1;
grp2 += input2;
```

Only counts the lasted entered int, is there a way to have it add all the entered ints?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, even outside of the questions I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the condition inside while And also shift the totalling logic

```
 do{
    System.out.println("Make a selection:\n");
    System.out.println("A: Enter a number for Group 1.");
    System.out.println("B: Enter a number for Group 2.");
    System.out.println("X: Exit and total the numbers for each group.\n");
    System.out.println("Select your option: ");
    answer = keyboard.next();

    if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("A")){
        System.out.println("Enter int: ");
        input1 = keyboard.nextInt();        // add an int to grp1
        grp1 += input1;
    }
    else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("B")){
        System.out.println("Enter int: ");
        input2 = keyboard.nextInt();        // add an int to grp2
        grp2 += input2;
    }
    else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("X")){ 
    }                                       // exit and total
    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid option - Try again.");
    }                                       // Invalid input - restart

}

while (!answer.equals("X"));
keyboard.close();
```

This will make your do while loop running i.e showing options to user until they wishes to exit. And also group total would be updated properly. I have updated answer based on answer by @Devin Howard

Comment: Awesome - Thank you for the quick reply!

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two confusions.

1) The "while" line in your code applies to the "do" block *above* it. That means that based on where the grp1 += and grp2 += lines are, they will only ever be run once. I suggest moving those calls to the end of the loop. You could move each line inside the relevant if block so that the code is run every time the user successfully enters a number after A or B.

2) The while condition is asking if the user entered "A" or "B". It's saying if they did, continue looping by going back to "do". If they entered literally anything else (any invalid answer), it will stop and run the code after the "while" line. I think what you really want is `while (!answer.equals("X"))`, which will continue the loop until the user correctly enters an "X" character.

You'll also want to move those grp += lines up a bit.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help!